# How to measure gasoline:oil ratio for 2-stroke motor?

Tags: sensor, instrumentation

For some reason I am obsessed with instrumenting my small fishing boat.  I'd like to have a continuous measurement of the gasoline:oil ratio in both my main (70HP) motor and kicker (7.5HP); I have a tank for each, so a display for each.

I will be using an Arduino of some sort.  I'm not looking for the wiring or code, but what kind of sensor to use.  I'm assuming there is some sort of sensor that will give me a resistance or voltage or ?? change that's proportional to the gasoline:oil ratio (50:1 to 100:1 is typical).

Google turns up bazillions of air/gasoline sensors, but I doubt they'd work.

If nothing exists, I'll start experimenting.  But it's gasoline, so any pointers to existing work would be appreciated.

Comment: I know they use refractometers (digital automated ones exist) to measure the ethanol concentration in gasoline, so I expect you could experiment to see if it would work for the oil/fuel mixture.  You can get an inexpensive optical one to test the idea.

Comment: @JohnD  I've read about sensors for measuring concentration of ethanol in gas, which work by measuring speed of sound propagation.  These are commercially available, but I can't recall who makes them.

Comment: Can you use two flow meters and just assume that oil and fuel will mix properly?

Comment: @filo If they do not mix properly then any other sophisticated measuring method will depend on the location of a sensor anyway. So yes, just two cheap flow meters is all that is necessary. Although, I did a quick search and there are not many oil resistant ones, most are for water.

Comment: Just use a couple of fuel tank senders and calibrate each.